# Sending JSONObject from Android to Python

Tags: android, python, json, sockets

I have a server that accepts a JSONObject and an Android app that sends a JSONObject to the server. The problem is that the server doesn't like the format of the JSONObject it receives. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Android Client:

```
try{  
            Socket s = new Socket("67.194.98.244",13375);  
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            org.json.JSONObject json = new org.json.JSONObject();
            json.put("order", id);
            oos.writeObject(json);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();



        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And the python server:

```
class MyTCPServerHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        try:


            data = json.loads(self.request.recv(1024).strip())
            # process the data, i.e. print it:

            for key, value in data.iteritems():
                with print_lock:
                    print key, value

                if key == 'order':
                    SubmitOrder(value,self)
                elif key == 'status':
                    getStatus(value,self)
                else:
                    with print_lock:
                        print "no order"




        except Exception, e:
            print "Exception while receiving message: ", e
```

And here's the stack trace on Android:

```
09-21 21:53:49.804: W/System.err(27827): java.io.StreamCorruptedException
09-21 21:53:49.804: W/System.err(27827):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
09-21 21:53:49.804: W/System.err(27827):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
09-21 21:53:49.804: W/System.err(27827):    at com.austinn.hamster.Print.sendCommand(Print.java:173)
09-21 21:53:49.804: W/System.err(27827):    at com.austinn.hamster.Print$1$1.run(Print.java:92)
09-21 21:53:52.144: W/System.err(27827): java.io.StreamCorruptedException
09-21 21:53:52.144: W/System.err(27827):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
09-21 21:53:52.154: W/System.err(27827):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
09-21 21:53:52.154: W/System.err(27827):    at com.austinn.hamster.Print.sendCommand(Print.java:173)
09-21 21:53:52.154: W/System.err(27827):    at com.austinn.hamster.Print$1$1.run(Print.java:92)
```

Comment: "doesn't like" isn't helpful.  Please give exact error messages and traceback (if any).

Comment: "No JSON object could be decoded"

Comment: In the absence of anyone answering ;-), try pulling the `recv()` call out of the `json.loads()` call, so you can print the string you're receiving.

Comment: Ah, so it's dying on the Android side!  Sorry, can't help there - but that probably explains why the Python side isn't getting anything sensible to parse, eh?